# jQuery hover/delay/fadeIn div's

Tags: jquery, hover, delay, fadein, fadeout

I stumbled upon this jQuery snippet:

```
 $(".faded").each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
 });​
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RExZs/

Anyway I'm trying to turn it into a hover function, so when you hover over a nav-menu button, the div's fade in with this cool delay effect. And then when the mouse leaves, the div's should disappear. It's for a "STORE" button (anchor), so this will be used to display a list of products when they hover it.

So far all I've come up with is:

```
  $(".products").hover(function(){   // I added THIS line
   $(".products-list").hide().each(function(i) { 
   $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();  
    }); 
 });   // and of course, THIS line
```

The problem is that it starts displaying the div's as soon as the page loads, LOL.

Now, when I hover the "STORE" button, the effect is *perfect*, but then when the mouse leaves it starts all over again, reloading those div's.

Either help me, or tell me where I can go to get over my damn jQuery addiction. :)

Thank you!

Comment: how about a fiddle of your non working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate behaviour for mouse-in and mouse-out.

You also need to stop any existing animations when you toggle, with the extra `true` parameters telling it to empty the animation queue and jump to the end of the current animation.

```
$(".products").hover(function() {
   $(".products-list").stop(true).each(function(i) { 
       $(this).delay(i * 200).fadeIn();  
   }); 
}, function() {
    $(".products-list").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/tvCBq/ for demo

Comment: Unfortunately `.fadeIn()` will "remember" the partial opacity of any divs caught in transition. With multiple hovers you will eventually lose them all. Also the second parameter is a easing or a callback, why send it `true`?

Comment: @Sinetheta I'm not seeing that on my fiddle, perhaps because of the second `true` parameter.

Comment: Mouse in and out of `.products` before the animation is complete.

Comment: Oh man, it's beautiful but I can't get it to work on my site. Works perfect in the jsfiddle example, but not on my wordpress site. I'll play around with it and see, but I just wanted to say thank you.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's conflicting with some of the other snippets I have in footer. For example, img lazyload stopped working. Is there an easy way to insert this without conflicts? I'll search for "no conflict" info, thanks again.

Comment: I've tried all of your fiddles (thanks Sinetheta, Alnitak) but for some reason they conflict with other things I have going. Which is strange. I setup wordpress to load the most recent jquery from google.

Comment: If you're having conflicts then you'll need to provide more code, an example with a bug recreated, or a link to your page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want your "mouseout" effect to be. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RExZs/558/)

```
$(".products").hover(
function(){
   $(".products-list").each(function(i) { 
       $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();  
   }); 
},
function(){
    $(".products-list").stop(true).show().hide();
});​
```

PS: you should always try to use the most recent version of jQuery. You will see that by mousing in and out of `.products` quickly you can change the order in which the items fadeIn. If however, you use jquery 1.7 instead of 1.4 they will always fade in the right order. It appears jQuery has changed how animations are queued in the interim.
[jQuery 1.7.2 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RExZs/559/)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed something. The problem with these is when you go to click one of the divs, they fadeout.

Comment: Sure, that's because I was answering the question you asked. Change the mark-up slightly by making `.product-list` items children of `.products` and you have yourself a nav menu. I've edit the fiddles accordingly.